# Ubuntu 13.10 keyboard shortcuts being ignored

Tags: unity, gnome, shortcut-keys, compiz

As I was unable to specify some keyboard shortcuts (e.g. lock computer and show desktop - my changes were being ignored after rebooting) through Ubuntu's system settings, I installed compizconfig-settings-manager and xbindkeys.

Unfortunately this happens to have caused some other shortcuts to break and I'm now unable, for example, to move between workspaces.

I have already confirmed both via dconf editor and org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings and compizconfig-settings-manager, that move-to-workspace-* entries have the right configuration, still the shortcuts don't work even after reset and rebooting.

I have also uninstalled compizconfig-settings-manager and xbindkeys, expecting that would revert the new problem but that didn't happen. Additionally I went through the hotkeys troubleshooting guide ( https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Hotkeys/Troubleshooting ) and confirmed that the keypress events are being correctly identified.

Is there any "deterministic" way to configure shortcuts in Ubuntu 13.10 or at least debug them so I know what is causing them to be ignored?